# How has my blog been getting pageviews from news.google.com?

Tags: blogger, page-views, google-news

I don't know how but my blog has been getting pageviews from `news.google.com`. How is it happening? Is it possible that my posts would show in Google News?

Comment: Did you apply to Google News for feed syndication?

Comment: No. I didn't apply.. How to apply to Google News for feed syndication?

Comment: That's a separate Question, but here goes - http://support.google.com/news/publisher/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=40787

Comment: I presume you mean you are receiving referral traffic from news.google.com?

Comment: Have you registered for Google Adsense?

Comment: No i didn't register..

Answer (score 1):

There have been instances where Google has detected a blog as a news feed and provides access to it through Google News. When this happens you will see referrer traffic showing up from news.google.com and when the actual indexing of your content happens you will see pageviews showing up as news.google.com as the news crawler indexes the news articles in your blog.